# Starting openoffice calc and open csv file

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, export-to-csv

I have a function in my .NET C# application which export data from `DataGridView` to `CSV` file, and opens the file with `Excel`.

Is there a way to do this using `OpenOffice Calc` instead?
I.e. 
How can I start `Calc` application from my code and pointing to the `CSV` file I have made?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article for you

http://www.opendocument4all.com/download/OpenOffice.net.pdf

And this code gives you an idea;

```
XStorable2 xs = (XStorable2)mxDocument;

xs.storeToURL("file:///C:/oo.xls", new unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[0]);
```

I also found this links for you

[Creating an OpenOffice Writer Document with C#](http://www.suite101.com/content/creating-an-openoffice-writer-document-with-c-a123686)

[Creating an OpenOffice Calc Document with C#](http://www.suite101.com/content/creating-an-openoffice-calc-document-with-c-a124112)

[C# to OpenOffice Calc](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/ea144fef-0c7f-4204-aa02-125bfec81600/)

**EDIT**:

```
using System;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.lang;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.uno;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.bridge;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.frame;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.text;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.beans;

XComponentContext oStrap = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();

XMultiServiceFactory oServMan = (XmultiServiceFactory) oStrap.getServiceManager();

XComponentLoader oDesk = (XComponentLoader) oServMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop" );

string url = @"private:factory/swriter";
PropertyValue[] propVals = new PropertyValue[0];
XComponent oDoc = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 0, propVals);

string docText = "This will be my first paragraph.\n\r";
docText += "This will be my second paragraph.\n\r";

And then this is written to the body of the document:
((XTextDocument)oDoc).getText().setString(docText);

string fileName = @"C:\Reports\test.odt";
fileName = "file:///" + fileName.Replace(@"\", "/");

And then the file is saved to disk:
((XStorable)oDoc).storeAsURL(fileName, propVals);

((Xcomponent)oDoc).dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Soner Gonul** explained you how to export to `CSV`.

To open the file with OpenOffice Calc just get the path of the OpenOffice Calc executable and launch it with your file path in the arguments

```
Process.Start("pathToYourOpenOfficeCalc.exe","pathToYourCSVFile");
```

That's all.